# Opening Associated File (Not Regedit Issue)

Tags: vb.net

I am successful in associating files with my application (Extension *.dvk);
Also I managed to open them using the OpenFileDialog1 as below:

```
OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "DVK Files (*.dvk)|*.dvk"
```

The challenge is when I click the associated file, it will open my application, but it is empty;
The question is: How to open the application with that clicked file opened in it?

I have found this code, but did not work:

```
Dim fi As IO.FileInfo ' used to test for file properties
If My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Count > 0 Then
fi = New IO.FileInfo(My.Application.CommandLineArgs(0))
If fi.Exists Then
Select Case fi.Extension.ToLower
Case ".fred"
' do something with fred
Case ".wilma"
' do something with wilma
Case Else
' do something else
End Select
End If
End If
```

My registry modifications are as below:

```
Root: HKCR; Subkey: ".dvk"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "Quotation System"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue 
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "Quotation System"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "Quotation System"; Flags: uninsdeletekey 
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "Quotation System\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\Quotation System.EXE,0" 
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "Quotation System\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\Quotation System.EXE"" ""%1"""
```

Comment: I modified it to show what I did...

Comment: Please edit to show the registry info associated with your file extension's default command (the output of `assoc .dvk` from the command prompt, and then the resulting 'ftype` output (eg., `assoc .doc` shows `.doc=Word.Document.8`, and `ftype Word.Document.8` shows `Word.Document.8="C:\Apps\Microsoft Office\Office 12\WINWORD.EXE" /n /dde`).

Comment: I've posted the registry modifications in my original posting above...

Comment: I can figure the file and path for drag-and-drop, but not for doubleclicked file; any help will be appreciated.