# How to get file name and path when it is clicked

Tags: .net, vb.net

When I double click a file (*.dvk) associated with my application, it will open the application;
My question is how to tell the application the name of that file and its path?

Comment: Can you tell how is the association between file and application in your project. Are trying to access .dvk file using opendialog window or fileupload control.

Comment: Hi dotnetmirror; No; using the opendialog is very easy as you know the file name that you are opening; My problem is JUST to figure out the name of the file user double-clicked. I was successful in associating the *.dvk with my application in the registry, but when user double-click *.dvk, the application opened empty, because I do not know how to figure the name of the *.dvk clicked. Any help appreciated. I searched a lot but could not find any helpful solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have registered your application in the environment by default the opened file is the second command line parameter. If you haven't or for further details see [File Associations Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Heq for responding; I've tried everything in the link you've provided; did not work; my codes are posted in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671162/opening-associated-file-not-regedit-issue?noredirect=1#comment34538300_22671162

Comment: I can figure the file and path for drag-and-drop, but not for doubleclicked file; any help will be appreciated.